# How to add 10000 rows of data to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, insert, hashmap

before adding into the database,the data should be checked.There are three columns of items should be unique.So I create a HashMapper(HashMap Map) to restore the datas already exists in the database.

```
HashMap<String, Object> eauMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

So there is a select operation from the database,and I make the three different of keys to mapping the same object.

```
List<Object> existObjectList = Service.getAll();
        HashMap<String, Object> Map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Object existdata : existEauList) {
            Map.put(existdata.getip1(), existdata);
            Map.put(existdata.getip2(), existdata);
            Map.put(existdata.getip3(), existdata);
        }
```

Then I make a loop to check the each row of adding data by the function Map.get(key1),Map.get(key2),Map.get(key3).If there is null, I put the data into the list and I put it into the map,too.

```
for loop:
  Object data = (Object) Map.get(ip1);//ip1 is from the cell value
    if (data == null) {
        data=(Object)Map.get(ip2);
        if(data==null){
              data=(Object)Map.get(ip3);
           if(data==null){
                 …………………………
                 Map.put(ip1,newdata);
                 Map.put(ip2,newdata);
                 Map.put(ip3,newdata);
                }
            }
     }
```

And then I commit the list to the database.
It works when there is only 300 rows of data. Now I add 10000, the server breakdown. How can I do to improve the efficiency.
The requirement need to point out the which row is repeat.and the project is set up by springmvc+spring+mybaits

Comment: Do you use prepared statement and addBatch to add these records ? Usually batch execution will give you better performance than individual inserts. Which server gives you the problem ? MySQL or any java process that you are running ? Do you have any error or stack trace when the server breaks down ? Does it go out of memory ?

Comment: I use mybaits and addBatch to add these rescords.I deploy my project to local tomcat. But When I import data,I waitting for 50 seconds,and myeclipse breakdown and stop.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add thousands of records to any rdbms, you should be using the features provided by the rdbms for importing data.

In MySQL the feature for importing large amounts of data is called [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

In the target table create unique index or primary keys on the fields that need to be unique. In the `load data infile` statement specify the `ignore` clause so that the import will not stop if it encounters a duplicate entry:

```
load data infile 'filename' ignore into table yourtable ...
```

UPDATE

If you need to identify the duplicate records, then

1. Create a temporary table with the same structure of the target table.
2. Import all data into the temporary table using `load data infile` statement.
3. Using a simple `select` with `inner join` between the temporary and the target tables will give you the records that already exists in the target table.
4. Using `insert ... select ... from temp_table left join target table on ... where target_table.identifier_column is null` command insert only those records from the temporary table into the target table that do not exist in the taget table. In the where condition you may have to specify more than 1 column if the combination of the 3 columns identify uniquely the records.
5. Drop the temporary table. (Or just close the db connection)

Comment: yes,but the requirement need to point out the which row is 
repeat.If I use this code to ignore the repeating datas,how Can I reach the requirement?

Comment: Next time pls share any requirements in the question, not just in follow-up comments. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes.thanks but how can I apply this to springmvc+spring+mybaits?

Comment: So I should write function to change the excel file to csv?

Comment: Unfortunately, `load data infile` cannot load data from and excel file, so if that's what your data is in, then yes you should convert it to csv.